# How can I prevent the source file is different from when the module was built when using Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

While I'm debugging I get this error:

> the source file is different from when the module was built

or the debugger does not go to the line that is faulty.

So I searched stack overflow's Website and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087390/the-source-file-is-different-from-when-the-module-was-built) but none of the suggestions offered worked for me.

I removed Visual Studio and All my extensions then Removed them from regedit.exe(hkcu and hklm) and %Appdata% (local and Roaming). Then I reinstalled everything(new Versions)

- Visual studio 2013 update 4
- Resharper(12.0.31101.0)
- Visual Assist 10.9 (2052)
- DevExpress-20140923

Then I noticed [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq3xz.jpg):

As seen on the [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq3xz.jpg) as soon as I run (F5) the code it looks like something edits the lines. I think that's why I get:

> the source file is different from when the module was built

If I look At the Undo List their is two misery Items called "Smart delete"
and when I remove Resharper the bug disappears. I also found this [unanswered Question on Resharper](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-390152)

For those three reasons think it's Resharper, but I'm not sure...
I Have found that selecting a entire line, or going to design view stops this behavior,
But that is annoying to do every time i run the project.

**What can I do to stop this annoying behavior?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto:

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> General -> Uncheck Apply Cut or Copy commands to blank lines when there is no selection

Comment: Thank You, This seems to do the Trick! its probably because of the Visual Studio Update 4 interfering with re-sharper or something like that...