# Visual Studio 2017 is reading old lines of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a web api in C#, and there was an error. There are two solutions I'm using for this (I was following two separate tutorials) and I imported one into the other to make sure the classes were available. This was working fine for a while, but now the changes I made to the imported files aren't updating; the code is crashing on an empty line where I'm pretty sure there was a errant line of code before, leading me to think somehow the compiler isn't getting my new code.

When I run the debugger and step into these external files, I get the alert that "Source File: (dir of imported class) Module: \Appdata\Local\Temp\Temporary\ASP.NET Files\vs...\FormUI.exe (the project I'm importing) Process: [18324] issexpress.exe
The source file is different from when the module was built. Would you like the debugger to use it anyway?" Selecting yes gives what I assume is old code (but VS displays the new code, leading to a crash on what seems to be a empty line), while selecting no lets me select the file manually. Doing so just repeats the prompt.

I've tried [following this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087390/the-source-file-is-different-from-when-the-module-was-built) and clean/rebuilding to no avail.

**Solution**

In my %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache folder, I found there was a duplicate a folder named after my solution. After cutting the properties from the duplicate and pasting it into the original (which was empty), my code worked again. I suspect this happened due to me adding the project to another solution and then removing it after consideration.

Comment: Here are somethings that you may try to solve the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa That was helpful, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Which step was the solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Clean the Solution

Step 2 - Examine the Full Path to the file in the Properties pane, where VS is getting your file directory from.

Step 3 - Hover your mouse over your opened file's tab and check that path. Should be at the top of your screen's window and visible via a Tooltip.

Step 4 - Compare Step 2 and Step 3's results
Chances are that the Properties pane's Full Path is not the same path as the opened files directory... you are opening and editing a file with the same name as your solution file, but it is in another directory...

You've simply opened a duplicate named file, which is not in your solution...but because it has the same name as the file in your solution...you think it is the correct file you are changing.

Comment: The files aren't in the web api's solution, but I'm importing it from another project. I checked while in the second, imported solution and the paths are consistent.

Comment: After messing around in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache I found there were two folders with my solution name! after copying the files from the duplicate into the original, that fixed it.