# Source file not found / Source file is different - how to avoid unloading and reloading the project?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019, debug-symbols

I am trying to debug a quite simple application in Visual Studio, but breakpoints are not working. When an exception occurs and I click on some methods I'll get error messages like

> Source not found

and

> Source file is different

and

> The breakpoint will currently not be hit. The source file is different from the original version.

There are only 2 ways for me to make debugging work again:

- restart Visual Studio
- unload the project and reload it

Both has not been needed during the last 18 years of my C# development carreer. How can I get Visual Studio to compile and debug just as it should?

The affected file in this case is `App.xaml.cs` in a relatively small project. I have this problem with other files in almost all solutions I work with, so this looks much like a Visual Studio problem to me.

I don't want to disable Checksums or similar in order to make breakpoints work. I just want the thing to work - there's no reason that the code and the binary are different (see below).

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise 16.11.9 at the time of posting this question. Updating to 16.11.10 did not help either (same problem a day later).

For reference, here's what I tried as an alternative to restarting or unloading:

- rebuilding of the solution - it rebuilds successfully but doesn't affect debugging

  ```
  Rebuild started...
  1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MetalPanda, Configuration: Release Any CPU  ------
  1>  MetalPanda -> D:\...\MetalPanda\bin\Release\MetalPanda.exe
  2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MetalPanda.Test, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
  2>  MetalPanda.Test -> D:\...\MetalPanda.Test\bin\Release\MetalPanda.Test.dll
  ========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
  ```
- clean + rebuild of the solution lie OP of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3087390/480982) - it rebuilds successfully but doesn't affect debugging

  ```
  Clean started...
  1>------ Clean started: Project: MetalPanda.Test, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
  2>------ Clean started: Project: MetalPanda, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
  ========== Clean: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
  ```
- according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8181907/480982) I also made sure that "Build" is checked in all configurations

  [image: Build is checked]
- according the same answer I made sure I unchecked "only build startup project and dependencies on run" (although that should be sufficient, because it is my startup project)

  [image: Build only startup project and dependencies]
- checking whether some process changes the file after it has been compiled. I am using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with the filter `Path contains App.xaml.cs` but I can't see any write access.

  [image: Process Monitor result]
- I have staged my changes in Git in order to be able to notice any differences in the file. There are no differences.
- I have added an extra line `Debug.WriteLine("Just for StackOverflow");` in order to check whether that actually gets compiled into the code. I can see its output, so it is compiled and the source code matches the binary

  ```
  [...]
  'MetalPanda.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MetalPanda.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
  Just for StackOverflow
  'MetalPanda.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MetalPanda.exe): Loaded 'D:\...\MetalPanda\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. 
  [...]
  ```
- I rebuilt each individual project of the solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7614528/480982). (I only have 2: the startup project and the unit tests). Each project builds successfully, but that has no effect on debugging.
- I deleted both `bin` and `obj` subfolders as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18835508/480982). Deleting them was possible, which also proves that the executable is not running otherwise, preventing a rebuild.